# Concern about fair coin toss probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we're not sure if we want to go out or not.
We decide to test our luck and we start tossing a fair coin.
We set this ground rules :
If in the string composed by H's and T's TT appears before HT we decide to go, else we stay home.
What is the probability that we're going out ?

I really thought hard but with some friends we settled that the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$, by thinking that every coin toss i independent , thus the probability of going out is P(T)*P(T).

But this doens't feel right to me because of two reasons:

- nothing assures me that the first coin toss is an H.
- even if the first toss would be an H then no matter how long we wait eventually a T will come up.
  So it seems "more frequent" HT than TT.

Anyone can explain me what kind of argument is right for this situation ?

Comment: Related: [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game).  The end result here is that if the game has not yet concluded and a head is ever tossed, before two tails can have both occurred to end the game the first of those two tails will have occurred and will necessarily have followed a head.  It follows then that the only way for TT to win will be if it was not the case that a head had come up before the TT, and so TT wins if and only if the very first two tosses are specifically both tails.

Comment: Now... HT is not "more frequent" than TT.  Any pair of tosses are equally likely to have been HT as TT.  The whole point though is that we are not considering a sequence of pairs of tosses where it resets inbetween each... we are letting the previous toss continue into the next toss.  This is not the same as the scenario of rolling a $4$-sided die and seeing whether a $1$ comes up before a $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you roll a $\sf T$ first then either you roll a $\sf T$ second (and have $\sf TT$) or you roll a $\sf H$ second.   Now *whether* you roll *that*, or a $\sf H$ first, this will be followed by an indefinite sequence of $\sf H$ until you roll a $\sf T$.

Thus you will roll $\sf\ldots TT$ before $\sf\ldots HT$ only if you roll *tails* on the *first two rolls*, which occurs with a probability of $1/4$.